# convert decimals into negatives?

Tags: javascript, math, scale

I'm scaling an image in css with transforms.

The scale goes from 0 to whatever, with 0 through 1 being smaller than the image.

I need to get the scale into negatives, so that 0 is the same size as the original, 1 is double the size, and -1 is half the size.

I have vars:

```
var cssScale, factorScale;
```

How to get cssScale into factorScale and vice versa?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want 2-to-the-power-of-n:

```
cssScale= Math.pow(2, factorScale);
```

To get back the other way would be log-base-2, which you'd have to implement using log-base-E:

```
factorScale= Math.log(cssScale)/Math.LN2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like cssScale = Size * (2 ^ factorScale).